# Can I say 'stopping'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Do they use a word *stopping* in a meaning *not going*? 
For example:

> Is the car going? No, it is stopping.

Does this sound good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better synonym for "not going" would be "stopped". To say the car is stopping means that it is slowing down and coming to a stop, but it is still going.

Is the car going? Yes, but it is stopping (still moving).

Is the car going? No, it is stopped (not moving anymore).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Is the phrase 'The train stops for two hours' fine ?

Comment: Yes indeed, that sounds perfect.

Comment: And one more little question. What is the best way to say about  what a car is doing when it is stopped using -ing form ?  Does the phrase 'The car is standing' fit ?

Comment: "Standing" works if you're in the car and ready to move it - otherwise, you're just parked. If the car is running, you could say "idling". If the car isn't running, I can't think of a good way to use the -ing form. The -ing form describes things happening at the present moment, and if the car is still and not running, it's not really doing anything at that moment. It's probably just "stopped" or "parked".

Comment: What do you think about the phrases: "The car is not going, it `is still` (it `is stationary`, it is `at a standstill`)" ?